# How do I set metadata with aws s3api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to make my CloudFront hosted blog redirect `/feed/atom/index.html` to `/index.xml`.  I have the following script that is supposed to set up redirect headers for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

redirect() aws s3api copy-object                 \
   --copy-source blog.afoolishmanifesto.com$1    \
   --bucket blog.afoolishmanifesto.com --key $1  \
   --metadata x-amz-website-redirect-location=$2 \
   --metadata-directive REPLACE

redirect /feed/atom/index.html /index.xml
```

After running the script I get the following output:

```
{
    "CopyObjectResult": {
        "LastModified": "2016-03-27T07:26:03.000Z", 
        "ETag": "\"40c27e3a5ea160c6695d7f34de8b4dea\""
    }
}
```

And when I refresh the object in the AWS console view of S3 I do not see a `Website Redirect Location` (or `x-amz-website-redirect-location`) piece of metadata for the object in question.  What can I do to ensure that the redirect is configured correctly?

Note: I have tried specifying the metadata as JSON and as far as I can tell it made no difference.

**UPDATE:** I have left the above question the same, as it still applies to metadata, but if you are trying to create a redirect with aws s3api you should use the `--website-redirect-location` option, not `--metadata`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not able to create a key `/feed/atom/index.html` in the bucket, so no metadata attribute was not created. Instead you should create `feed/atom/index.html`. I'll modify it like:

```
#!/bin/sh

redirect() aws s3api copy-object                 \
   --copy-source blog.afoolishmanifesto.com/$1    \
   --bucket blog.afoolishmanifesto.com --key $1  \
   --metadata x-amz-website-redirect-location=$2 \
   --metadata-directive REPLACE

redirect feed/atom/index.html /index.xml
```

In my solution, notice `/` in `--copy-source` and the first argument to redirect script missing the leading `/`